# Is there a tree database or tree suggestion engine out there?

Tags: trees

I have a dead tree on my HOA grounds that needs to be replaced. I love trees but I'm far from an expert. It would be awesome if there was a database I could search against, where I could specify things like location, light amount, root spread pattern (deep vs shallow), and branch spread pattern, and get recommendations from that.

Does anyone know if such a resource exists? I tried a few Google queries without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arborday is what you want.  http://www.arborday.org/trees/treeGuide/advancedsearch.cfm

They also have a forum.  You can sign up and ask questions of arborists and tree lovers.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to consider - if this is near a street or utilities, many municipalities keep lists of trees they recommend for placement in those areas. These would be trees that have proven to deal well with your climate and with the particular stressors of your area.